# Why isn't my python log populating despite the rest of the function running properly?

Tags: python, logging

I am utilizing try-except statements that utilize logging but, even though the log file is being generated, no logs are being created.

Initially my code worked, but it was incorrectly formatted for production: Try except statements that tried running scripts and, upon their failure, pushing log statements to a log.

I was told "Imports -> Functions -> Run functions" + "Functions should have try-except logging, not the other way around".

I've modified my code for this question to isolate the problem: In this code, we have a script that opens a json. The script opening the JSON works. The logging is the only issue.

Where am I going wrong?

When rearranging the code, the script still runs, excluding the logging portion.

```
import logging

LOG_FORMAT = "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s - %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(filename='C:\\Users\\MWSF\\Documents\\log_test.log',
                   level=logging.INFO,
                   format=LOG_FORMAT)
logger = logging.getLogger()

def get_filepath():
    '''Find the file path, which is partly defined by the file name.'''
    try:
        return "C:\\Users\\MWSF\\Documents\\filename.json"
    except Exception:
        logger.error("Error occured while determining current JSON file path.")
    else:
        logger.info("Successfully determined current JSON file path.")

path = get_filepath()
```

Intended result: A function that opens a specified file and a log named `log_test.log` that has this information:

`INFO 2019-04-26 14:52:02,260 - Imported current JSON file.`

Actual result: A function that opens a specified file and a log named `log_test.log` that has this information:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the return on the "else" clause rather than under "try". It causes the function to exit rather than doing the logging.

```
def get_filepath():
    '''Find the file path, which is partly defined by the file name.'''
    try:
        #return "C:\\Users\\MWSF\\Documents\\filename.json"
        path = "C:\\Users\\MWSF\\Documents\\filename.json"
    except Exception:
        logger.error("Error occured while determining current JSON file path.")
    else:
        logger.info("Successfully determined current JSON file path.")
        return path
```

Sample log_test.log:

INFO 2019-04-29 12:58:53,329 - Successfully determined current JSON file path.